# Is there a way for pika get list of all routing_keys for a particular RabbitMQ exchange?

Tags: pika

I have some code that uses `pika` to bind routing_keys to a RabbitMQ exchange:

```
ROUTING_KEYS = ["a", "b", "c"]

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameter(host=whatever, port=whatever, ...)
with pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=parameters) as connection:
  channel = connection.channel()
  channel.exchange_declare("my_exchange")
  channel.queue_declare("my_queue")
  for key in ROUTING_KEYS:
    channel.queue_bind(queue="my_queue", exchange="my_exchange", routing_key=key)
```

This works.  But if I later change `ROUTING_KEYS` to be `["b","c","d"]` it will correctly add "d" but it will *not* remove "a".

Is there a way to get the currently registered routing_keys of "my_exchange" so that I can compute the difference and automatically remove the ones that are no longer part of `ROUTING_KEYS`?

Thanks for any advice.

---

**edit**

Alternatively, is there any way in the message_callback to work out what the matching binding key was from RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1):

> But if I later change ROUTING_KEYS to be ["b","c","d"] it will correctly add "d" but it will not remove "a".

You would have to use the `queue_unbind` method to remove the `a` binding.

> Is there a way to get the currently registered routing_keys of "my_exchange" so that I can compute the difference and automatically remove the ones that are no longer part of ROUTING_KEYS?

You could use the [HTTP API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.10.1/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html) to get the list of bindings for a queue:

```
/api/queues/vhost/name/bindings
```